# Proving $(a_n) = \cos(\log(x))^{\infty}_{n=1}$ does not converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was hoping for some feedback on proving the sequence $(a_n) = \cos(\log(x))^{\infty}_{n=1}$ does not converge. I am really struggling with approximating the integer values such that I can find subsequences converging to $\cos(0)$ and $\cos(\pi)$.

Let $N$ be contained in the natural numbers, and let $k\geq N$. As $k \rightarrow \infty$, $\lim((k+1)/k) = \lim(1) = 0 < \epsilon$.

This implies that the change in the function becomes infinitesimally small as we approach larger values of $k$.

Therefore, we see that that for sufficiently large $k$, for any $a > 0$ the $\log(k)$ will be within $[2m\pi -a, 2m\pi +a]$ infinitely many times for $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Equivalently, the $\log(k)$ will be within$ [2(m+1)\pi -a, 2(m+1)\pi +a]$  infinitely many times for $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Take $n_1$ = 0. Let We form a first sub-sequence by setting $n_k$ , for all k>1, such that:
\begin{align*}
    |\cos(\log(a_{n_k})) - \cos(0)| < 1/k
\end{align*}
We therefore recursively build a sequence such that $\lim(\cos(\log(a_{n_k})) = \cos(0) = 1$. Therefore, the subsequence $(a_{n_k})^{\infty}_{k=1}$ converges to 1.

Now, we take $m_1 =0$, and for all $k > 1,$ we set $m_k$ such that
\begin{align*}
    |\cos(\log(a_{m_k})) - \cos(\pi)| < 1/k
\end{align*}
We therefore recursively build a sequence such that $\lim(\cos(\log(a_{m_k})) = \cos(1) = -1$. Therefore, the subsequence $(a_{n_k})^{\infty}_{k=1}$ converges to -1.

Since a convergent subsequence cannot have two convergent subsequences that converge to different limits, the $\cos(\log(a_n))$ does not converge.

Comment: The natural logarithm $\log(x)$ has branch points at $x=0$ and [complex infinity](https://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/ComplexInfinity/) (see [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/04/04/)), but since $\log(x)$ is a multi-valued function it also requires a branch cut in the complex plane. Wolfram Language's convention places the branch cut at $(-\infty, 0]$ (see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithm.html) and [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/04/05/)).

Comment: Assuming this convention $\cos(\log(x))$ also has a branch cut at $(-\infty, 0]$ (see [WolframAlpha evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot3D%5BIm%5BCos%5BLog%5Ba%2B+I+b%5D%5D%5D%2C+%7Ba%2C+-5%2C+5%7D%2C+%7Bb%2C+-5%2C+5%7D%5D)). With respect to your real-analysis tag, doesn't $\cos(\log(x))$ converge for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ except at $x=0$ assuming this convention) ([see WolframAlpha Evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%7BRe%5BCos%5BLog%5Bx%5D%5D%5D%2CIm%5BCos%5BLog%5Bx%5D%5D%5D%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-10%2C10%7D%5D))?

Comment: I am sorry Steven, this seems very helpful but I am afraid it is beyond my level of understanding. I believe I am only considering values of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ -- which I do not think I made clear. Perhaps this is the misunderstanding? Therefore, as far as I can tell, this sequence can only converge to values between [-1,1].

Comment: The function $\cos(log(x))$ converges for $\forall x>0$. Of course $$-1\leq \cos(\log(x)) \leq 1,\quad x>0$$ since $$\log(x)\in\mathbb{R},\quad x>0$$ and $$-1\leq \cos(y) \leq 1,\quad y\in\mathbb{R}.$$ So I'm not sure what you mean when you say it doesn't converge.

Comment: Or do you mean $\underset{x\to\infty }{\text{lim}}\cos(\log(x))$ doesn't converge since $\underset{y\to\infty }{\text{lim}}\cos(y)$ is indeterminate?

Comment: I had meant to ask for help proving $(a_n) = \cos(\log(x))^{\infty}_{n=1}$ does not converge. I was trying to show this by showing it had two convergent subsequences to different limits. I believe I incorrectly stated my question and have edited it now to hopefully better reflect what I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

(I don’t have enough reputation to comment, so I will use the answer option to help you). Try considering the subsequences $x_n = e^{2n\pi}$ and $y_n = e^{(2n+1)\pi}$.

Comment: I thought about taking this approach, but I was thinking that $x_n=e^{2n\pi}$ would not be a natural number. Would this essentially be searching for terms of such that $x_n = e^{2n\pi} + a$, such that $|\cos(log(a))-\cos(0)|<\frac{1}{k}$?

Comment: @magentapanda An approach similar to this still works. Consider $x_n=\lfloor e^{2n\pi}\rfloor$ and $y_n=\lfloor e^{(2n+1)\pi}\rfloor$.